# Updating an EDMX database with new columns

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm using an edmx database to place data onto a map which until this point has been working absolutely fine. Problem is, I realised I needed another column. So I went into SQL Server Management Studio and added that column. After some looking into, i thought that going into the edmx and 'refreshing' the tables would enable to get data from the new columns. However, if i try and do that, even just try and show the value in an alert, my map ceases to exist... this is kind of a problem. Am i doing something wrong???

Comment: deleting and re-adding the table seems to be the most stable way of getting the changes from the DB

Comment: Hmm. OK. Maybe I'll try that. I've got a backup incase I break it :P

Comment: Refreshing the EDMX from the database will add new columns in. ***BUT*** manual edits to the EDMX (eg. better naming for associations) will be lost for any tables that are updated by the refresh.

Comment: Oh ok. Well I've gone ahead and deleted and re-added. It's made some more problems but should hopefully be fixable. fingers crossed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Update your EDMX no need to delete and re-adding EDMX :

```
-> Right Click on EDMX
-> Select Click Open
-> Right Click On Page
-> Select Update Model From Database EDMX
-> Save your changes
```

**Hope This will hell you !!**

Comment: I think with a combination of everyone's help it's now working. thank you